# modprobe: can't open 'modules.dep': No such file or directory

Tags: module, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Working with x86 platform, and trying to insert (any) KO with modprobe, it seems like path prefix of the modules.dep is missing/not configured (as the error in the title).

modules.dep is placed in: /lib/modules/3.12.17/module_deps/modules.dep.

What is missing?

Thanks,

SB.

Comment: Run `depmod -a` first. What `uname -a` tells you?

Comment: @0andriy ... the first tells my mostly the same, the latter works and tells me the kernel-info you'd expect. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564946/how-to-do-the-hello-world-example-from-githublinuxkit-linuxkit